# Creating a new window in Electron when specific keys are pressed only when the electron app window is in focus?

Tags: javascript, electron

How do I create a new window in Electron when specific keys are pressed only when the electron app window is in focus?

And yes there are a lot of solutions posted but none have worked at all, here is all the things I've tried so far

`window.addEventListener` as well as `document.addEventListener` in `renderer.js`, globalShortcuts work but of course it's "global" so it'll enact out even when the electron app is out of focus, tried [`mousetrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mousetrap) to work around this yet still to no avail... none of it works.

Comment: Use [`win.isFocused()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winisfocused) from inside your GlobalShortcut handler to check if the window is in focus. Or if you want to use `addEventListener` instead, then use Electron's IPC modules to send a message back to the main process when a key is pressed, then create your BrowserWindow in the main process.

Comment: @Joshua so like `if(win.isFocused()) { const ret = globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+N", () => {console.log("now new window!");})}
`

Comment: More like `globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+N", () => { if (win.isFocused()) { console.log("now new window!");} })` with the `win.isFocused()` inside the GlobalShortcut handler.